# modify color of the Chinese part of a Drupal website

Tags: html, css, drupal, class

On a website, there are 2 languages installed. Chinese (i18n-zh-hans) and English (i18n-en). Both body's have different classes.

*Chinese*

```
<body class="front not-logged-in one-sidebar sidebar-left i18n-zh-hans">
```

*English*

```
<body class="front not-logged-in one-sidebar sidebar-left i18n-en">
```

I want to give the Chinese version some different styles. So I thought I change this:

```
 body
  {
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    background-image:url(images/margins.jpg);
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: auto !important;
  }
```

to this:

```
body .i18n-zh-hans
 {
    color: red;
  }
```

For displaying the Chinese text in red (just an example). But for some reason, it doesn't work. Are my declarations wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove space between body and class :

```
body.i18n-zh-hans
```